# How much data traffic does watching YouTube take?

Tags: video, download, internet-connection, youtube

How much usage does watching a video on YouTube take? Does it depend on the length of the video? The quality?

I'm trying to figure this out because I use a lot of online tutorials at work, and I don't want to suck the download limit dry before anyone else has a chance to use it.

For reference, the videos I watch are generally 30 mins - 1hr, at 360p (standard).

Comment: 'How heavy is a piece of string?' - The answer really depends on the length, format and resolution of your videos.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek have added length and quality for reference.

Comment: Can you clarify "download limit"?  If the data plan from the service provider has a monthly allotment of data bytes, the answer will be different than if you are talking about bandwidth limits (how much data everyone can get through the connection in a given time).  Quality will affect both, length won't affect bandwidth.  Do you know what bandwidth is available?  How many people will be watching videos at the same time?

Comment: @fixer1234 sorry didn't realise I put both of those terms in the title originally. I was looking for how much data watching videos uses, not the bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends heavily on the length, quality and file format of the video. You can see the total amount of data used on any given video by right-clicking on the video to bring up this menu:

[image]

Then, you can click `Stats for nerds` and bring up this prompt:

[image]

The `Bandwidth` option is what you're looking for. It shows a graph, along with real-time data of the current amount of bandwith being used.